# can I set the device language/culture from within xamarin android app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to change the device country and culture settings from within an app. I gave the app change configuration permission but did not succeed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `OnCreate` method of your Activity, you can do something like this:

```
Java.Util.Locale.Default = new Locale("pt", "BR");
Resources.Configuration.Locale = Java.Util.Locale.Default;
Resources.UpdateConfiguration(Resources.Configuration, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
```

Comment: Thks! works perfect! i tried this b4 but forgot to restart the activity after the language change.